# Rails 3.1 before_create on create method only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my ProductTrackListing model:

```
acts_as_list :scope => :product_id
before_create :set_initial_position, :only => :create

private

def set_initial_position
   self.position = self.track.position
end
```

In my controller I have the standard Create method which handles the initial tracklisting which is copied from a parent 'release', where it copies the parent release track positions.

I have another custom method called 'add_catalogue_track' set up to handle additions that need to always be added at the end via acts_as_list regardless of the parent release track position.

I initially though the before_create call referred to the controller create method but it's being called on my custom method as well. So in short, my question is how to I make before_create only apply to the create method, I tried `add_catalogue_track' but that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`after_create` is triggered by anything that calls `Base.save`, and is a new record. The `create` method is actually just a convenience method for calling `new` and `save` at once.

Are you using `create()` or `new()` and then `save()` in `add_catalogue_track()`? If so, that would be what's triggering the callback.

One thing you can do is use `skip_callback` in your custom method:

`ProductTrackListing.skip_callback(:create, :before, :set_initial_position)`

Comment: Yes, I am using new() so that's what's triggering it. This worked perfectly thought so thank you!! Even though it worked, i'm not sure I understand the syntax, would be handy to know....i'll google it though. Thanks again.

Comment: @RyanBerry, no prob. Check out this apidock page for more info on the method: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_callback. Also, if this worked for you please mark the answer as correct. Thanks!